# Is Popeye shown in the Narcos Series?

Tags: character, narcos

I recently found out about [John Jairo Velásquez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Jairo_Vel%C3%A1squez) - [Popeye](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQy_LJdZ7qw&t=414s). I do not remember anyone with that name in the *Narcos* series.

Is he even in there? If so, who is playing him?

Comment: No character of that name is listed on IMDB. Nor do I recall seeing anyone of that name/sobriquet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty positive you see him when his youngest son Moreno does his first job. He's in the tunnel with the drugs because they do a quick zoom in to his face before the scene cut.

Comment: In which Episode is that? Is that the only time?